# how to get values of image alt="..." in php?

Tags: php, parsing, preg-match-all, alt

hi all i got many sets of data show below(in $code variable).  i wonder how i can output all values of image alt="..." ? For example i want to get : **Music Club ( sun ) Music 09**

from:

```
        <img src="http://www.example.com/teststorage/episodes/11224/201.jpg" alt="Music Club ( sun ) Music 09" />
```

sample set of data:

```
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 item">
        <div class="portfolio-item">
            <a href="http://www.example.com/en/test/1234/11224/Music 09" title="Music Club ( sun ) Music 09" class="portfolio-item-link" >
                <span class="portfolio-item-hover"></span>
                <span class="fullscreen"><i class="icon-play"></i></span>
                <img src="http://www.example.com/teststorage/episodes/11224/201.jpg" alt="Music Club ( sun ) Music 09" />
            </a>
            <div class="portfolio-item-title">
                <a href="http://www.example.com/en/test/1234/11224/Music 09" title="Music Club ( sun ) Music 09" class="portfolio-item-link"><h4>Music 09</h4></a>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You don't. You don't process html with regexes. You use DOM and maybe xpath, e.g. `//img/@alt`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you realy want to use `preg_match_all` you could use the following code.

```
<?php
$str = <<<END
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 item">
        <div class="portfolio-item">
            <a href="http://www.example.com/en/test/1234/11224/Music 09" title="Music Club ( sun ) Music 09" class="portfolio-item-link" >
                <span class="portfolio-item-hover"></span>
                <span class="fullscreen"><i class="icon-play"></i></span>
                <img src="http://www.example.com/teststorage/episodes/11224/201.jpg" alt="Music Club ( sun ) Music 09" />
            </a>
            <div class="portfolio-item-title">
                <a href="http://www.example.com/en/test/1234/11224/Music 09" title="Music Club ( sun ) Music 09" class="portfolio-item-link"><h4>Music 09</h4></a>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
END;

preg_match_all('/<img(.*?)alt=\"(.*?)\"(.*?)>/si', $str, $out, PREG_SET_ORDER);

//see first output
var_dump($out);

/*
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(105) "<img src="http://www.example.com/teststorage/episodes/11224/201.jpg" alt="Music Club ( sun ) Music 09" />"
    [1]=>
    string(65) " src="http://www.example.com/teststorage/episodes/11224/201.jpg" "
    [2]=>
    string(27) "Music Club ( sun ) Music 09"
    [3]=>
    string(2) " /"
  }
}
*/

//clean array
$alt = array();

foreach($out as $val) {
  $alt[] =  $val[2];
}

//see cleaned output
var_dump($alt);
/*
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(27) "Music Club ( sun ) Music 09"
}
*/
?>
```

If you want to do the right thing however, I would look into [simple_html_dom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/). You can do something like:

```
<?php
// Create DOM from URL or file
$html = file_get_html('http://www.example.com/page_i_want_to_spider.php');

// Find all images
foreach($html->find('img') as $element)
       echo $element->alt . '<br>';
?>
```

Comment: hugo desing many thanks your preg match all worked but how to use the var_dump($out) array values as hyperlinks title  ?> <a href="./test.php?id=/&<?php  echo $alt ; ?>"> <?php echo $alt ; ?> </a> <br /> <?

Comment: Realy, listen to all the advise and dont use it!! Just check the simple_html_dom or casimire et hippolyte's answer.

Comment: in the foreach wherr i fill `alt[]` you can also use an echo of $val[2] to show it

Answer (score 1):

if you have html code like below then you can do it like this

```
$re = '/(alt)=("[^"]*")/'; 
$str = '<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 item">\n        <div class="portfolio-item">\n            <a href="http://www.example.com/en/test/1234/11224/Music 09" title="Music Club ( sun ) Music 09" class="portfolio-item-link" >\n                <span class="portfolio-item-hover"></span>\n                <span class="fullscreen"><i class="icon-play"></i></span>\n                <img src="http://www.example.com/teststorage/episodes/11224/201.jpg" alt="Music Club ( sun ) Music 09" />\n            </a>\n            <div class="portfolio-item-title">\n                <a href="http://www.example.com/en/test/1234/11224/Music 09" title="Music Club ( sun ) Music 09" class="portfolio-item-link"><h4>Music 09</h4></a>\n            </div>\n            <div class="clearfix"></div>\n        </div>\n    </div>'; 

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```

output:

```
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => alt="Music Club ( sun ) Music 09"
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => alt
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => "Music Club ( sun ) Music 09"
        )
```

Comment: thanks for reply. i tried your solution nothing was printed out! the imput data is not in one line as your example it is in blocks as shown in my first post. could you tell me how to fix it ?

Comment: to print you need to do `print_r($matches);` in the end

Comment: i did use print_r($matches) but no output!

Comment: @user1788736 what are you going to use the `alt` text for?

Comment: i am using the alt value for the hyper link titles. I create the hyper link and use the alt values in the title of hyperlinks

Answer (score 1):

With DOMDocument:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($html);

$imgs= $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');

foreach ($imgs as $img) {
    if ($img->hasAttribute('alt')) echo $img->getAttribute('alt') . '<br/>';
}
```